# Obtener la información de las notificaciones push recibidas en segundo plano en Android al arrancar la App directamente desde su icono

Tags: android, notificaciones, push, procesos-en-segundo-plano

La aplicación recibe perfectamente las notificaciones tanto cuando está en primer plano como cuando está en cuando está en segundo plano o cerrada. Cuando está en primer plano es la aplicación la que recibe la notificación y los datos de dicha notificación se recogen en el método "onMessageReceived". Cuando la aplicación está en segundo plano, es el sistema de Android el que genera la notificación y los datos se recogen en un "Intent" que recibe la activity principal. Según todos los ejemplos que he encontrado, es desde la propia notificación donde se puede arrancar la App y obtener los datos de ella. Esto lo tengo implementado, pero me falta poder obtener los datos cuando yo arranco la aplicación desde el icono de ésta con el numerito de las notificaciones que tiene pendientes de ser atendidas. En este último caso el "Intent" que se obtiene al arracar la aplicación no lleva ninguna información de la notificación y no sé como extaer esa información ni siquiera mediante el array de "StatusBarNotification[]" donde obtengo las notificaciones recibidas en la barra.

```
private void obtenerInformacion(){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        StatusBarNotification[] notifications=notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();

        if(notifications.length>0) {
            Notification notification = notifications[0].getNotification();
            String texto = notification.get_algo();
            Log.e("TEXTO NOTIFICACION", texto);
        }
    }
```

Utilizo este método ejecutado desde el onResume() pero no hay ningún método en "notification" que me deje obtener ni siquiera el título o mensaje de la notificación.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisar [ask] para modificar el formato de tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Añadí algo de código para que se sepa un poco más lo que busco.